# Fetch all records from database before a specific date

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing an `android` application which calls an `api` made in `php` to get the list of service requests stored in the `MySQL` database. The table has `scheduled_date` column which has the date stored in it in the following format: `21/5/2021`.

I want to get all the records before today so for example, if I booked a service yesterday and scheduled it for lets say `28/5/2021`, then when I load the app on `28/5/2021`, the `api` should also return me this scheduled service along with other requests but the `api` never returns it.

I am storing two types of requests in my table.
One is of the regular type and the other one is the scheduled one so for that, I have put two columns in my table (`is_scheduled`, `scheduled_date`) so if the request is of regular type, then scheduled_date is set to be `NULL` by default and is_scheduled is set to be No by default.

Below is my logic that I have implemented so far.

```
$today_date = date('d-m-Y');

$get_scheduled_date = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_requests WHERE is_active = 0");
$req_array = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($get_scheduled_date) > 0){
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_scheduled_date)){
        $date_got=$data['scheduled_date'];
        if(!is_null($date_got)){
            $formatted_date=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date_got));
            if($today_date<$formatted_date){
                $req_array[] = $data;
            }    
        }
        else{
            $req_array[] = $data;
        }
        
    }
    $newArray = array("available_requests"=>$req_array);
    json_response(200, "", $newArray);
}else{
    $req_array = array();
    $newArray = array("available_requests"=>$req_array);
    json_response(200, "", $newArray);
}
```

Comment: Please store the date in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format

Comment: @RiggsFolly Actually, I am storing two types of requests in my table. One is of the regular type and the other one is the scheduled one so for that, I have put two columns in my table (is_scheduled, scheduled_date) so if the request is of regular type, then scheduled_date is set to be NULL by default so in that case, I think this query might fail, no?

Comment: Just goes to show, a full and complete question is a thing of beauty

Comment: @MSalman It would be better if you store Regular type as is_scheduled = 0 & scheduled_date=today

Answer (score 1):

My logic is absolutely fine. Just changing the date format to `Y-m-d` did the trick.

Comment: thats what i said

Comment: Thank you for the hint @IndraKumarS. I didn't know format matters in this case because as you can see, I was already using d-m-Y format for both dates and it wasn't working so I changed the format to Y-m-d and it started to work due to unknown reason. Any reason why it was not working for d-m-Y?

Comment: @MSalman that's because by formatting the dates before comparing them, you're then doing a string comparison, not a date comparison. And in d-m-Y format the dates will not always be in date order when compared as strings. e.g. 14-04-2021 will show as being earlier than 31-03-2021 even though in date terms it's later. String comparisons for greater/less than will start with the first character, and 1 is less then 3. Whereas with Y-m-d it will be equal all through 2021 and only when it gets to 4 and 3 will it decide which is greater (i.e. later)

Comment: @MSalman But really for date purposes you shouldn't do string comparisons of any kind. They're dates, not strings. e.g. you could get the timestamps of both using strtotime and compare those timestamps (simple integer comparison, very reliable, no ambiguity) or you could parse both dates into DateTime objects and use the diff function of that class to compare them. Either way is better than comparing raw strings. **Dates are not strings** (repeat out loud 100 times or until it is branded indelibly onto your brain).

Comment: @MSalman lastly you didn't need PHP for this at all, it would have been a lot more efficient to use SQL to simply select all rows which are before today (or where the scheduled date is null). Then you wouldn't have to compare them using PHP, you could just fetch all the rows from the query directly into your array. The only problem with that is that you said _The table has scheduled_date column which has the date stored in it in the following format: 21/5/2021_ ...again: **dates are not strings**. MySQL has a `date` column type for storing dates...use it!!